# Missing '[' at message send expression

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

Am getting this error message and matched my brackets and couldn't find anything wrong. Can you find what's wrong?

Thank you.

Error message is commented out on the relevant line; filename is MyHorizLine.m:

```
#import "MyHorizLine.h"

@implementation MyHorizLine

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
  self [super initWithCoder:decoder]; //Missing '[' at message send expression
  if (self) {
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

  }
  return self;
}

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
  CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  CGContextMoveToPoint(c, 0, 0);
  CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, self.bounds.size.width, 0);
  CGContextStrokePath(c);

}
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing an `=`:

```
self [super initWithCoder:decoder];
```

should be

```
self = [super initWithCoder:decoder];
```

Comment: Thank you for catching that. I was checking my braces so much I missed the "=" sign.

Answer (score 1):

The line should read

```
self = [super initWithCoder:decoder];
```